# Measuring Efficiency at Various Loads in LTSpice

Tags: ltspice, spice, efficiency

If one wishes to know the efficiency of a circuit in LTSpice, it is reasonably simple to set up the simulation to give you an efficiency report:

Select Simulate -> Edit Simulation cmd and select 'Stop simulating if steady state is detected'. 
Rerun the simulation. 
Select View -> Efficiency Report -> Show on Schematic. The efficiency report appears on the schematic.
(Instructions stolen from [this website](http://www.simonbramble.co.uk/lt_spice/ltspice_lt_spice_tutorial_3.htm), other sources are available)

This efficiency report is useful for more than just in/out power, but also where the losses are: diodes, transistors, transformers etc. as shown here:
[image: Screenshot of LTSpice showing efficiency table]

However, this only works if, there is one fixed input (a voltage source) and if there is one fixed output (a current source or resistor called RLOAD)

Which is fine if you have a known fixed load, or only a couple of fixed states.

Is there a method to get the full efficiency report out for a bunch of points? For example, I have a DCDC converter and I need to know how it performs when 0.1, 0.2, 0.3 .... 1.9, 2.0, 2.1W is drawn, and where the power goes (U1, U2 etc).

I'm sure there is a way of doing a batch of runs for a set of options, but I cannot find how to do so for the efficiency reports.

Comment: You can always hack together you .meas commands and step through values

Comment: @PlasmaHH Looks like Mike says that's exactly how to do it! My answer isn't really an answer, so I'll either modify it or delete it when I get a moment. If you answer, then I'll just delete mine. I'm not sure how to get the full report for the OP's question using .MEAS.

Comment: @jonk You can use these `.meas` commands, for example, assuming `V1` is the input source, `V(i)` is the input voltage, `R1` the load and `V(o)` the output voltage: `.meas Iin rms(-I(v1)) trig time=6 targ time=10
.meas Vin rms(V(i)) trig time=6 targ time=10
.meas Pin param Vin*Iin
.meas Pout avg(V(o)*I(R1)) trig time=6 targ time=10
.meas eff param Pout/Pin`

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen Thanks very much. Will attempt. If you can write up a nice answer, I'd be happy to delete mine. Otherwise, if I get time to verify and amend my answer, I'll try and do that.

Comment: Forgot to add that the input is `sin 0 1 1` and the simulation is `.tran 10`, while the whole circuit is a lowpass `RL`, that's why I wait 6 periods. I measure over 4 for better accuracy, sometimes it "averages" the minor variations.

Comment: Go ahead, I'm about to go back to some coding attempts. :-)

Comment: Good thing I forget things this morning. You can shorten the commands by merging the `rms()` in the `.meas` cards, but this way is more visible and it saves the intermediate results for better analysis.

Comment: @jonk: I personally often hack together things with .meas commands due to the efficiency report only working if ltspice has any way to detect steady state, which often is not the case. The possibility to select a time range in .meas commands comes in very handy here. I personally don't use stepping though, because it can be buggy, especially if you use it to switch out components. Externally driving python scripts make things a bit more convenient

Comment: @PlasmaHH I need to learn to use it well, it seems. Too bad it will delay any improvement in my answer. I don't think, from what I've read in the help and what you've both mentioned here, that this is ANYWHERE near as easy to use as the efficiency report. Probably why the OP asked.

Comment: From the comments I can't tell if "it is known": the efficiency report is only valid (i.e. can only be activated) if an LTspice native switching component is placed in the schematic, LTspice has to be able to detect its presence, otherwise it won't work. To be able to use the report elsewhere, it's enough to simply place one of those devices in the schematic (preferably the simplest), grounded, but unconnected. It will still count towards the matrix solver, but at least there will be multiplying by zero; then the efficiency report can be activated.

Answer (score 4):

You can do a batch of runs by adding a .STEP PARAM card, if you add the "Don't reset T=0 when steady state is detected". So you could adjust your RLOAD using such a parameter value. The problem is that the Efficiency Report will only reflect the last run, I think. LTSpice can't produce more than one of them.

You can get a feel for how LTspice's software handles the Efficiency Report by simply adding a card or a part, like a resistor, below your circuit somewhere. The report will "magically" move itself below all the parts. So there is a bit of software going on that is inside the schematic display code. And I doubt that this display code has access to more than one data structure for the report. One reason is that if such data were an array of such structures, then the display code would have to figure out how to display all those reports, automatically. And I suspect that Mike didn't want to have to go figure out some complex "nice appearing" output for that. Another reason is that the efficiency report is probably "hacked in" because the sales department demanded it for LTspice as a way to make selecting their power converter chips easier and more convenient and competitive with others who also have ways to providing such reports for their own parts. And since the sales department didn't *require* supporting multiple reports, there was no need to "go there."

I've been able to generate multiple runs, no problem, with the .STEP card and with a .OPTION card to play with SSTOL values. So the Spice engine will do it. And I'm sure the data *could* easily be placed into an array of structures, with a count, too. I'm pretty sure Mike wouldn't have a problem there. So I think it probably won't happen unless someone gives Mike a convincing and clear algorithm that just "sings beautifully" in his mind and is easy to implement, regarding the display of such results from the engine. He probably has very little motivation to provide several reports. But he might be interested if he can clearly see *how* to do a reliable job in a way that won't cause any additional support phone calls.

(The sales team, I am sure, already accepted the need for support calls regarding ONE such report. It's needed, competitively. So it's a no-brainer. They have to bite that bullet. But they might not be very happy if Mike goes out and adds something that makes the calls more expensive and more frequent, without first asking their permission. Might be able to sneak it in, if he feels there won't be any such problems.)

---

Another possible suggestion for Mike would be another option on the .TRAN simulation, where it displays the report on the schematic (like it does already) and then merely prompts after each .STEP PARAM for hitting ENTER or something like that to move on to the next .STEP PARAM value. This wouldn't add any changes to the display code, wouldn't add any changes to the Spice code generating the data, and would only add an arcane (and ignored by most people) option allowing this special bit of code pausing before moving to the next .STEP PARAM value. Mike might buy that idea.

I already know that it works, because I can perform a series of simulations right now with the existing product. And it displays the Efficiency Report of the *last* simulation. So it just picks up the data from the last run. So it's certain that adding a prompting dialog would be pretty easy to do, very clear to Mike, and may have a chance.

---

I've written to Mike. I will see what he says about all this.